# How to check if element ID exists in HTML document

Tags: html, vb.net

Hello I'm trying to use an IF statement to check if an element exists in a html doc. The element I need to search is an ID called "account_pulldown". Is there a simple way of doing such?

[image]

I have looked around and can not seem to find a method that does such. Here is an example of the idea I had.

```
        If WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("account_pulldown").exists = True Then

            'Exists
        Else
        End If
```

Comment: Did you try `If (WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("account_pulldown") IsNot Nothing) Then` ?

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli That works thanks!

Comment: Since `GetElementById()` will return null/Nothing if no such id is found, the answer is that pointed by @GabyakaG.Petrioli

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli I will keep note of that for future ref's. Cheers.